# .net Webforms Error raised due unknown reason, it shows null reference

Tags: windows, webforms, webforms-routing

I have done my best to remove this error but i find no actual way to dot this.. in the end i connect to server using remote connection and copy bin folder to desktop and then copy the same folder back.. and magically it starts working. Can anyone has any tips that will be very very nice

[Image for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2DXS.png)

Comment: Hi Bhai! Welcome to S.O! It would be really helpful for us if you can show us code snippets of what codes/methods which caused that null reference exception! U might want to use the command "Ctrl+K" shortcut while inserting your codes in!

Comment: thing is that its not just the code but the whole application